# Select elements with text contents?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to select all elements with direct text contents. So given the document

```
<div>
 <h1>Hi</h1>
 <article>
   <p>blah balah blah</p>
   <p>blah blahrg blarg</p>
 </article>
 <footer></footer>
</div>
```

I would like to select the h1 and p elements (so 3 elements total). Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(){
    var ignoredNodes = {
    "script" : true,
    "noscript" : true
    };

    jQuery("*", "body").filter(
        function(){
        var c;

        if( this.nodeName.toLowerCase() in ignoredNodes ) {
        return false;
        }

        c = this.firstChild;

        return c && c.nodeType === 3 && jQuery.trim(c.data);
        }
    );

    //[<h1>Hi</h1>, <p>blah balah blah</p>, <p>blah blahrg blarg</p>]
})()
```

Comment: I am not sure if `c.data` is cross-browser, there is also a `nodeValue` property that has the text content. The trim is required to filter out empty text nodes, such are created when you have newline after div

Comment: nice one Esailija , I guess that he'll want to remove all non semantic  elements like <script> in the body element so maybe you should add a rule excluding <script> and <noscript>

Comment: nice catch @alonisser, feature added :)

Comment: It still works fine for me even at this page. If the `nodeType` returned is 1 for a given `node`, it's a regular html tag and you need to access `childNodes` of the given `node` to see text nodes(`nodeType 3`).

Comment: thanks for the clarification @Esailija- glad to learn something new!

Answer (score 1):

I think this was answered here:
[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)
with both jquery and pure javascript solutions